# Reasonable default window size for application

Tags: user-interface, resize, screen-resolution

Since there're to much possible screen size, and possible dpi (both mobile and desktop). What is the best way to have a good default window size on all possible platform (windows, linux, mac)?

There are some people that suggests to always maximize your window on the first start and remember the window geometry. But AFAIK on Mac OS/X doesn't usually maximize a window.